# ‘ilutGLLoadImage’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux

Приветствую, товарищи! Достал из закромов наработки по OpenGL+OpenAL+DevIL, которыми я некогда занимался под Ubuntu. Ныне же пересел на Arch и решил это дело скомпилировать. Компилятор выдаёт сабж. Причем на предыдущие инструкции

```
ilutInit();
ilutRenderer ( ILUT_OPENGL );
```

компилятор внимания не обратил. Библиотеки подключены:

```
#include <IL/il.h>
#include <IL/ilu.h>
#include <IL/ilut.h>
```

Компилирую командой

```
g++ main.cpp -o mygame -lGL -lGLU -lglut -lopenal -lIL -lILU -lILUT
```

Под Ubuntu всё компилировалось играло и плясало. Подозрение на пакет [devil-ilut](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/devil-ilut/), который пришлось ставить из AUR'a, поскольку в официальном репозитории devil без ilut'a.
Тем не менее результат команды "cat /usr/include/IL/ilut.h | grep ilutGLLoadImage":

```
   ILAPI GLuint ILAPIENTRY ilutGLLoadImage(ILstring FileName);
```

т.е. функция в заголовочном файле присутствует, но компилятор говорит not declared.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение: исправил в PKGBUILD пакета devil-ilut ( из AUR )

```
--disable-opengl
```

на

```
--enable-opengl
```

Answer (score 1):

Если какой-то заголовок компилятор не нашел бы, то он выдал бы сообщение об ошибке, так как он обязан загрузить этот заголовок в единицу компиляции.

У вас нет соответствующего сообщения об ошибке, что заголовок не найден.

Следовательно проблема в вашем коде, а не в компиляторе.

Проверьте, может быть это имя помещено в какое-нибудь пространство имен, а вы не указываете то пространство имен, где это имя объявляется.

Comment: У меня прописано в начале всего "using namespace std;", но врядли это имеет значение. ‘ilutGLLoadImage’ находится в функции main() сразу после инициализации функций glut и ilut. На них компилятор не ругается.

Comment: @Roman Что вам мешает просмотреть соответствующий заголовок? Может быть эта функция - функция -член класса?

Comment: Эта функция находится в рамках условия #ifdef ILUT_USE_OPENGL ... #endif. Другие функции в этих рамках так же выдают not declared. Не слишком хорошо понимаю как это работает, но подозреваю, что условие ILUT_USE_OPENGL не выполняется, отсюда и проблемы.

Comment: @Roman Очевидно. Прежде, чем что-то использовать, хорошо бы было сначала ознакомиться с описанием, как это использовать.:)